# .htccess redirect from non-www https to www-https

Tags: linux, ssl, redirect, https

I want to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com for my website. Can you help me with the code to put it on .htaccess file. the site is in magento.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help understanding .htaccess](http://serverfault.com/questions/107460/need-help-understanding-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

There you go

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but it isn't working, i want from HTTPS non-www to HTTPS . both are in https, i have non-www http -> https www and HTTP with www to -> HTTPS WWW but i need NON-WWW HTTPS TO WWW-HTTPS .

Comment: You should add one additional condition - ```RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on``` or ```RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$```

Comment: it doesnt work as well, i need HTTPS://example.co.uk to HTTPs://WWW.example.co.uk it is in magento, the .htaccess file just has order deny,allow  deny from all written in it. i have place the code below it.